# Is there a way to install an extra apt package for a flatpak app?

Tags: flatpak

I've installed Okular using flatpak. I require to open `.djvu` files which can be achieved by installing `okular-extra-backends`.

Since the app is installed in a sandbox, it won't use my system's libs even if I installed it. So I'm wondering if I can install this onto whatever container flatpack is using or if it's not possible.

Comment: An update: there is a flatpak enter command which is supposed to give you access to sandbox, but it's unclear how okular is installed inside of it. Because I'd have expected kde-runtime to be available, but when I try to install things via apt it just seems that this "sandbox" only has packages which exist on my host and not the packages of the application (okular)

Comment: here is a page [link](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html)that may be of help. Though I have not tried it myself. Sounds like  you can grant access to the host file system and thus should be able to grant the program access to the needed extra-backends if you know where on the file system it resides.